# Removing a specific value from a txt file with python

Tags: python, file

The user inputs the data (first_name, last_name, phone number and the phonebook name they want to save it at) and the script will save it to a .txt file. However, when I'm trying to delete a specific value that the user has inputted, it's not quite working correctly.

1) It won't delete a single entry in the .txt file. The program will hang until I do ctrl + c.

2) I ran the test with three entries and it deleted them all except one.

3) The function cannot find the first_name, last_name values in the .txt file and spits out the error. It only finds the first entry in the .txt file, not the third one for example.

Any feedback would be helpful. Thanks.

```
def delete(first_name, last_name, phonebook_name):
    filename = '%s.txt' % phonebook_name

if not os.path.isfile(filename):
    print('phonebook.py: error: phonebook doesn\'t exists')
    quit()

with open(filename, 'r+') as f:
    for line in f:
        entry_first_name, entry_last_name, entry_number = line.strip().split('\t')
        if entry_first_name == first_name and entry_last_name == last_name:
            lines = f.readlines()
            f.seek(0)
            for data in lines:
                if data != entry_first_name and entry_last_name:
                    f.write(data)
                    f.truncate()
                    print(print('phonebook.py: contact deleted'))
                    quit()
        else:
            print('phonebook.py: error: contact doesn\'t exist.')
```

Comment: Sounds like you should be using `fileinput` with `inline=True` -- this will simplify your code significantly.

Comment: I think you would want the `f.seek(0)` before `lines=f.readlines()`. Also, you are comparing `data`, which is essentially a line, against `entry_first_name`, which never should be true. `bool(entry_last_name)` will always will be true...`

Comment: The reason your program never finishes might be because you use `f.seek(0)` on the same file you are already looping over, effectively resetting the loop in every iteration.